Rain stains on bricks newly built appartement
After a few days of heavy rain, there are rain stains visible on the bricks of my recently built apartment. The wet stains are located directly below my upper neighbour’s terras. These stains didn’t disappear after 3 dry days; the stains even expanded in size. What could cause this issue given the apartment was newly built? Could this cause moisture issues? How to solve this? Thanks

Pictures always help on something like this.  Do all the units have a same problem?  Maybe something washed off your neighbor's terras.
